# python generator is too slow to use it. why should I use it? and when?

Tags: python, performance, generator, list-comprehension

Recently I got question about which one is the most fastest thing among `iterator`, `list comprehension`, `iter(list comprehension)` and `generator`. 
and then make simple code as below.

```
n = 1000000
iter_a = iter(range(n))
list_comp_a = [i for i in range(n)]
iter_list_comp_a = iter([i for i in range(n)])
gene_a = (i for i in range(n))

import time
import numpy as np

for xs in [iter_a, list_comp_a, iter_list_comp_a, gene_a]:
    start = time.time()
    np.sum(xs)
    end = time.time()
    print((end-start)*100)
```

the result is below.

```
0.04439353942871094 # iterator
9.257078170776367 # list_comprehension
0.006318092346191406 # iterator of list_comprehension
7.491207122802734 # generator
```

generator is so slower than other thing. 
and I don't know when it is useful?

Comment: that is not a very accurate way to measure computing time... i suggest you try with `timeit`.

Comment: `range` by itself is iterator. `xrange` is it's generator  equivalent

Comment: @przemo_li that depends on the python version; `xrange` does not exist in python3.

Comment: @hiro but, it's already big difference performance between `iterator` and `generator`. I don't know `timeit` well now, I think it will not be better in that situation. thx.

Comment: @przemo_li http://treyhunner.com/2018/02/python-range-is-not-an-iterator/ this blog says `range` is not an iterator. Its good to read.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that when you do the timing, `list_comp_a` is not a list comprehension, it's a list that was created with a list comprehension

Comment: `time.time()` returns seconds. So results should be `0.0004`s, `0.009`s, `0.00006`s, `0.007`s. or something. Provided values are only good to provide relative differences.

Comment: A proper test does not show the same extreme divergence for generators: https://repl.it/repls/IndianredImmediateTests

Comment: @deceze thx. there are problem, `np.sum` is not proper, I should use `sum`

Comment: @przemo_li it looks like you don't grasp what "iterator", "iterable" and "generator" are in Python nor how they relate to lazy evaluation. Py2's `range()` is a function that returns a `list` (which is iterable indeed but not an iterator), and `xrange()` is a class that implements the "iterable" protocol to lazily generate values during iteration but is not a generator either.  A generator is an instance of the `generator` class (a generic iterable class) which is built from either a generator expression or a generator function (a function using the "yield" keyword).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`generators` do not store all elements in a memory in one go. They `yield` one at a time, and this behavior makes them memory efficient. Thus you can use them when memory is a constraint.

Comment: This answer highlight distinctive advantages of `generator` over other constructs. It should be market as accepted answer.

Comment: I would also suggest adding that generators also let you build data from high latency sources. For example, if you're querying a database then with a generator you can start `yield`ing results as soon as they come in, without waiting for the full data set

Comment: @SimonFraser logically true.

Comment: Just figured it might not be obvious to the question asker :)

Comment: @SimonFraser it may be an answer to his `when ?`

Comment: You are confusing "generators" with "generators functions" (and "generator expressions" FWIW). A `generator` is just an iterable  that is built from a generator function or expression and uses this function or expression to generate values during iteration. FWIW generator functions can do what they want with memory and eat all your ram if they want to. The point here is that what makes a custom iterable (potentially) more memory efficient than a list or other sequence type is the use (of absence of) of lazy evaluation in the iterable/iterator implementation itself.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers your explanation is valid. But `we all are adult here` and we are supposed to write `generator functions` with `lazy evaluation`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @KishorPawar nothing in generator functions mandates lazy evaluation, lazy evaluation is not a feature of generator functions (even if they make it easier to implement for quite a few cases), and there's actually more to generator functions than just lazy evaluation (mainly the support for coroutines). So why easy lazy evaluation is indeed the main use case for generators both concepts are not strictly equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

As a preamble : your whole benchmark is just plain wrong - the "list_comp_a" test doesn't test the construction time of a list using a list comprehension (nor does "iter_list_comp_a" fwiw), and the tests using `iter()` are mostly irrelevant - `iter(iterable)` is just a shortcut for `iterable.__iter__()` and is only of any use if you want to manipulate the iterator itself, which is practically quite rare.

If you hope to get some meaningful results, what you want to benchmark are the *execution* of a list comprehension, a generator expression and a generator function. To test their execution, the simplest way is to wrap all three cases in functions, one execution a list comprehension and the other two building lists from resp. a generator expression and a generator built from a generator function). In all cases I used `xrange` as the real source so we only benchmark the effective differences. Also we use `timeit.timeit` to do the benchmark as it's more reliable than manually messing with `time.time()`, and is actually the pythonic standard canonical way to benchmark small code snippets.

```
import timeit
# py2 / py3 compat
try:
    xrange
except NameError:
    xrange = range

n = 1000

def test_list_comp():
    return [x for x in xrange(n)]

def test_genexp():
    return list(x for x in xrange(n))

def mygen(n):
    for x in xrange(n):
        yield x

def test_genfunc():
    return list(mygen(n))

for fname in "test_list_comp", "test_genexp", "test_genfunc":
    result = timeit.timeit("fun()", "from __main__ import {} as fun".format(fname), number=10000)
    print("{} : {}".format(fname, result))
```

Here (py 2.7.x on a 5+ years old standard desktop) I get the following results:

```
test_list_comp : 0.254354953766
test_genexp : 0.401108026505
test_genfunc : 0.403750896454
```

As you can see, list comprehensions are faster, and generator expressions and generator functions are mostly equivalent with a very slight (but constant if you repeat the test) advantage to generator expressions.

**Now to answer your main question**  "why and when would you use generators", the answer is threefold: 1/ memory use,  2/ infinite iterations and 3/ coroutines.

First point : memory use. Actually, you don't need generators here, only lazy iteration, which can be obtained by [writing your own iterable / iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) - like for example the builtin `file` type does - in a way to avoid loading everything in memory and only generating values on the fly. Here generators expressions and functions (and the underlying `generator` class) are a generic way to implement lazy iteration without writing your own iterable / iterator (just like the builtin `property` class is a generic way to use custom `descriptors` without wrting your own descriptor class).

Second point: infinite iteration. Here we have something that you can't get from sequence types (lists, tuples, sets, dicts, strings etc) which are, by definition, finite). An example is [the `itertools.cycle` iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

> Return elements from the iterable until it is exhausted.
>   Then repeat the sequence indefinitely.

Note that here again this ability comes not from generator functions or expressions but from the iterable/iterator protocol. There are obviously less use case for infinite iteration than for memory use optimisations, but it's still a handy feature when you need it.

And finally the third point: coroutines. Well, this is a rather complex concept specially the first time you read about it, so I'll let someone else do the introduction : https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/

Here you have something that only generators can offer, not a handy shortcut for iterables/iterators.

Comment: Bruno, the blog above you are referring to says `In Python, "functions" with these capabilities are called generators`, and in your comment on my answer says `I am confusing "generators" with "generators functions". `  I googled `generators` vs `generators functions` and found nothing related to both of them.  Do you have anything that explains how `generators` and `generator functions` are different like http://treyhunner.com/2018/02/python-range-is-not-an-iterator/ blog explains why `range` is not an `iterator`?

Comment: Quite simply : `generator` is a builtin class. Calling a generator function returns a `generator` instance, evaluating a generator expression returns a `generator` instance too.  So while we often use the term "generator" for both generator functions and generator expression because both _create_ generators, they are actually not "generators" by themselves. It's just like we usually call "method" a function defined in a "class" statement when it's actually really a function and only become a proper `method` instance when looked up on an object.

Answer (score 0):

I think I asked a wrong question, maybe. 
in original code, it was not correct because the `np.sum` doesn't works well.
`np.sum(iterator)` doesn't return correct answer. So, I changed my code like below.

```
n = 10000
iter_a = iter(range(n))
list_comp_a = [i for i in range(n)]
iter_list_comp_a = iter([i for i in range(n)])
gene_a = (i for i in range(n))

import time
import numpy as np
import timeit

for xs in [iter_a, list_comp_a, iter_list_comp_a, gene_a]:
    start = time.time()
    sum(xs)
    end = time.time()
    print("type: {}, performance: {}".format(type(xs), (end-start)*100))
```

and then, performance is like below. the performance of `list` is best and iterator is not good.

```
type: <class 'range_iterator'>, performance: 0.021791458129882812
type: <class 'list'>, performance: 0.013279914855957031
type: <class 'list_iterator'>, performance: 0.02429485321044922
type: <class 'generator'>, performance: 0.13570785522460938
```

and like @Kishor Pawar already mentioned, the list is better for performance, but when memory size is not enough, sum of `list` with too high `n` make the computer slower, but sum of `iterator` with too high `n`, maybe it it really a lot of time to compute, but didn't make the computer slow.

Thx for all. 
When I have to compute a lot of lot of data, generator is better. 
but,

Comment: Your benchmark is still wrong, as it compares apples with oranges.  For example `list_comp_a` is just a plain list so the test does not take into account the time required to actually __build__ that list.